# Setup of Qt Creator to debug into Qt classes

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to setup Qt Creator (3.0) in a way, that I can debug into the Qt classes. So I download the corresponding src code (http://gitorious.org/qt/qt5) and install it in a directory (e.g. `c:\Qt5\src`).

Then I have my own project. Where do I need to set the source code path of Qt (`c:\Qt5\src`), so I can debug my code, but also into a Qt class where necessary.

-- Edit:Pavel's comment --

Pavel has given a good hint: But I am using a precompiled version of Qt/Qt Creator. So I am basically looking for a solution which does not require me to compile from source. Nevertheless a useful hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using a prebuilt version just remap the source code location as described in [Mapping Source Paths](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-preferences.html#mapping-source-paths):

> **Mapping Source Paths**
>
> To enable the debugger to step into the code and display the source
> code when using a copy of the source tree at a location different from
> the one at which the libraries where built, map the source paths to
> target paths:
>
> - Select Edit > Preferences > Debugger > General.
> - In the Source path field, specify the source path in the debug information of the executable as reported by the debugger.
> - In the Target path field, specify the actual location of the source tree on the local machine.

To get "*the source path in the debug information of the executable as reported by the debugger*", you can activate the "**Use Tooltips in Stack-View when Debugging**" option by right-clicking in the Stack View and move the mouse over a specific function call.

Comment: In Windows build for debug often use CDB. For CDB we must go to Select Tools > Options > Debugger > CDB Paths, in the first edit put something like: C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64_opengl\bin, in the second edit put: C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\Src.

Comment: That last paragraph was the most important part for me. It was the missing step on all other posts. Worked great for MSYS2 pre-built binaries of qt 5.10.1 with mingw64.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Centos Linux 7, Qt Creator 4.1.0, Based on Qt 5.9.2 (GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64 bit). Creating most of the source path defined in the binaries I was debugging and symlinking from the end of that path into the location where I really had the source checked out did work though.

Comment: In Qt Creator 4.14.1 there is a button "Add Qt Sources" under Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General which automatically fills out the source path mappings. Worked perfectly. I installed the sources when installing Qt via the online installer.

Answer (score 8):

If you look into the tooltips, you will see references to `/Users/qt/work`, the Mac deployed debug symbols are pointing there. Of course, this is not documented, as these folks want you to buy enterprise.

If you create the `/Users/qt/work` directory (as root), then make a soft link to your source directory named qt, everything will work. No need to build anything from source (under Mac that would result in tens of gigs wasted). Same considerations about plugins

Example:

```
sudo -s
mkdir /Users/qt
cd /Users/qt
mkdir work
cd work
ln -s /Users/your_user_name/Qt/your_qt_release/Src qt
```

Everything will work. Any source mapping failed here, so leave those alone. 
Hope this helps

Comment: In case of Mac OS, Debugger > General > Source Paths Mapping  didn't work but symlink to /Users/qt/work/qt works. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Centos Linux 7, Qt Creator 4.1.0
Based on Qt 5.9.2 (GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64 bit)

Answer (score 4):

With Xcode, before you step into the Qt library the first time, enter the following command in the LLDB window:

```
settings set target.source-map /Users/qt/work/qt /path/to/Qt/5.10.1/Src
```

(Obviously you'll want to change the version number, as relevant).

But suppose Trolltech changes its build directory, what to do then?  (Or, how did the community wiki that gave the `/Users/qt/work/qt` path find it?)  You can guess what the path needs to be by editing `/path/to/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/QtCore_debug` (or any other Qt library) and searching for some paths.  "/Users" seems like a good guess.  About 2% into the library you'll start seeing sections with a lot of paths like:

```
../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel^@../../include/QtCore       
/../../src/corelib/tools^@global^@/Users/qt/work/qt/qtbase/src/corelib
/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/arch^@/Applications/Xcode.app
/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/<etc>
```

Look for an absolute path that looks like it could be writable.  (`/Applications/...` would not be a likely build path, for example)

Answer (score 3):

In recent Qt creator (v 4.11) press button "Add Qt Sources"
in Tools > Options > Debugger > General
and select Qt sources file.
Qt5 should be installed by online installer with checked "Qt Debug Information files".

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions from Qt [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html#debugging-tools-for-macos):

"In the run configuration, select *Use debug version of frameworks*."

Answer (score 1):

In Arch Linux, if using official packages, you can install debug packages, which has source code and debug symbols. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Debugging/Getting_traces#Installing_debug_packages).
For example:

```
pacman -S qt6-base-debug
```

Here are some of the files from package (`pacman -Ql qt6-base-debug`):

```
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/01/cbf19297a6d39a5de67b4f79e485eb46002659
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/01/cbf19297a6d39a5de67b4f79e485eb46002659.debug
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libQt6Concurrent.so.6.5.2.debug
/usr/src/debug/qt6-base/build/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include/moc_qabstractanimation.cpp
/usr/src/debug/qt6-base/qtbase-everywhere-src-6.5.2/src/dbus/qdbusabstractadaptor.cpp
/usr/src/debug/qt6-base/qtbase-everywhere-src-6.5.2/src/dbus/qdbusabstractadaptor.h
```