# Segfault with QColorDialog in Qt5.7 and macOS

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm new to Qt and trying to display a `QColorDialog` when the user clicks a button.

When I run my program and click the button, I get the color dialog to appear. I can open it and close it as much as I want, but when I exit the application I get a segfault.
However, if I run my application and don't click the button (so that the color dialog doesn't show up), I can exit it without segfault.
The code below is a minimal exemple of how to trigger the crash.

I'm running macOS 10.12 and Qt5.7.

Any of you having an idea of how to solve that problem?

---

#### `mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QPushButton *button;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void getUserColor();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

#### `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{

    button = new QPushButton("Choose your color");
    setCentralWidget(button);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
            this, SLOT(getUserColor()));
}

void MainWindow::getUserColor()
{
    QColorDialog::getColor();
}
```

---

#### `main.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Can you grab a backtrace of the crash?

Comment: I've tried to run it with Qt Creator debugger but it get to the *disassembler*. Would it be of any help? Also I can post the "backtrace" from Apple, if it helps.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The example I attached is enough to crash for me. As mentioned, I tried to run it in Debug mode with Qt Creator but it didn't help much.

Comment: @filaton Well, if your program crashes in debug, you can walk back the stack usually to see where it actually came from.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, but all steps I see in the stack point to some assembler code. See http://imgur.com/a/4CYiY for the content of the stack.

Comment: Actually I would like to determine firstly if my program is valid and the problem comes from macOS. Or is there anything obviously wrong in my code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's no "small program" suggested by title of one of your links. It has the entire Qt framework in the background. And the crash happens in the framework (because it happens at exit, and there's no exit handler or custom types with destructors in the code, so there's no actual application code getting run on exit).

Comment: One thing you could determine with debugger is, wether crash happens before `exec()` returns, or after it when your `main()` returns. Something like this: `int r = a.exec(); /* <-- breakpoint here */ return r;`

Comment: @hyde The _How to debug small programs_ link in this stock comment is only meant as a resort for actually small programs. The primary recommendation is to use the debugger.

Comment: @hyde The crash happens after it, when the `main()` returns.

Comment: @hyde And I cannot get a smaller example than this one. The crash seems to be strongly related to Qt, so I have no other choice than including the framework.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Another thing is, just asking OP to "step through your code line-by-line" is not very helpful for applications with event loop in a library, especially when crash is happening outside OPs code. At the very least instruction like that should include "get sources and debug symbols of the library, so you can step through library code to find out why it crashes".

Comment: @filaton That looks like a Qt bug... I'd try with different dialogs, like just message dialog, and see if it crashes then.

Comment: @hyde I tried with a font selection and didn't get a segfault. Still don't know if it's Qt or macOS bug.

Comment: I tested the exact question code on Win 10, Qt 5.7 (created a new QWidget project without .ui form, copypasted your 3 files into the generated files of the fresh project). Works flawlessly here. You might want to file a bug report.

Comment: ...or, if you are feeling adventurous and want to learn new things, figure out how to debug into Qt sources. If you can actually find the bug in the Qt code (*if* it is Qt bug, but that's probably more likely than compiler or Mac OS bug), it's far more likely to get fixed (especially if you can actually submit a fix patch...) :)

Comment: It appears to be platform-specific; I didn't manage to crash it on Qt 5.6.1 on Debian Testing.  You will need to attach a debugger and understand the backtrace.

Comment: @filaton - assembly code in debug display probably just means that your debugger doesn't know where to find the Qt sources.  You'll want to read its manual to see how to add them to its source path.  Make sure that the sources you use are those corresponding to the actual linked library, of course!

Answer (score 0):

This is a brief answer explaining some things, since the question problem itself seems to be a Qt bug in the currently latest release version, and so not really directly answerable at SO.

As said in the comments, your code works at least in Win10 Qt 5.7, and Debian Testing Qt 5.6.1. Additionally, it is mentioned that problem only happens with `QColorDialog`, other dialogs tested by OP do work. So conclusion is, that this a Mac OSX and `QColorDialog` specific issue. It could be a bug in Qt (most likely), but *could* theoretically also be bug in the operating system or in the compiler toolchain.

Things to do:

- Learn [how to debug into Qt sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469310/setup-of-qt-creator-to-debug-into-qt-classes).
- [Search if there is relevant bug already reported, and if not, consider writing a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) with your nice example, as well as exact platform information. It would be helpful if you can get a good stack trace including the Qt library (see above bullet point for how).